# Link the cloning of a project to a second project?

Tags: gitlab

Is it possible in Gitlab to force a cloning/checkout of a different external Project in a subfolder of the main Project1?

E.g.:

```
git clone Project1
```

```
Project1
--Subfolder Project1
--checkout Subfolder Project2
```

Push commands in the project2-folder should still be placed in project2.

If this is possible, is it a good practice or are there drawbacks using this principle?

Comment: I don't think this has to do with Gitlab, but it's a common git command: git submodule